# Python Need to print line from the text

Tags: python, string

I need to print each line with the word I search for

```
text = open("example.txt").read()
start = 0
while 1:
    found = text.find("python", start)
    if found == -1:
        break
    for line in found:
        print line
    start = found + 1
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (12 line)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot iterate over the integer `found`. Instead, iterate over lines in the file, and use the `if SUBSTRING in STRING` syntax;

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'python' in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: and that if the searching word more than once? how to print all strings with the desired word?

Comment: @user3584920 This will output all the lines that contain the word, so you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`found` is the (integer) location of "python", you cannot iterate over it.

You probably mean something like

```
found = text.find("python", start)
while found != -1:
    # Do something with found: 
    # ...
    start = found + 1
    found = text.find("python", start)
```

However, as you explicitly want to work with each line containing your word, it's best to start off with lines. Using

```
for line in open(filename):
```

or (see phihags answer)

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
```

is better than trying to handle all the text at once.